# bash shell script for reading a fields in a file and producing commands

Tags: bash, shell

I am new to bash shell scripting and would be thankful for suggestions of a script that can do this task. I have a file (list.cqt) with many lines. Each line has a list of fields separated by '/' in the following format:
/Field1/Field2/Field3/Field4/Field5/Field6/Field7/Field8/Field9/Field10

For e.g. the contents in list.cqt are:
/F11/F12/F13/F14/F15/F16/F17/F18/F19/F110
/F21/F22/F23/F24/F25/F26/F27/F28/F29/F210
...
/Fx1/Fx2/Fx3/Fx4/Fx5/Fx6/Fx7/Fx8/Fx9/Fx10

(I modifyied the names inside each field just for simplifying the problem. Only the number of fields is constant in each line. Contents in each field can be anything - numbers, characters, etc)

I need to write a script to execute the following command by reading each line from list.cqt:
command arg1 arg2 arg3 *arg4* *arg5* arg6 *arg7* arg8 arg9 *arg10*

Only *arg4*, *arg5*, *arg7* and *arg10* change for each line read. Rest all remain the same.
*arg4* is Field4 in that line in list.cqt
*arg5* is Field6 in that line in list.cqt
*arg7* basically starts with -1000 for the first command and changes in increments of 100. So for the second command it will be -900 for second command, so on, and 0 for 11th command, 100 for 12th command, 200 for 13th command etc.
*arg10* is same absolute value as *arg7* but with opposite sign. So if *arg7* is -600, *arg10* is 600. If *arg7* is 400, *arg10* is -400.

For example, reading the first two lines from list.cqt in the above example of the file, the commands will be:
command arg1 arg2 arg3 F14 F16 arg6 -1000 arg8 arg9 1000
command arg1 arg2 arg3 F24 F26 arg6 -900 arg8 arg9 900

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added `echo` before command because it's better to check if generated list is correct:

```
arg7=-1000
arg10=1000
while read line
do
  set $(echo $line | tr / ' ')
  echo command arg1 arg2 arg3 "$4" "$6" arg6 "$arg7" arg8 arg9 "$arg10"
  arg10=$((arg10-100))
  arg7=$((arg7+100))
done < list.cqt
```

If it is, just remove `echo` and run the script.

Here you process `list.cqt` line by line and set parts of its line to positional arguments of shell; then you use this parts as `$4` and `$6`. Variables `arg10` and `arg7` are increased/decreased each time a line from the `list.cqt` file is processed.

**Update**

You can also use arrays instead of positional arguments (thanks to Dennis Williamson and kojiro for the tip):

```
arg7=-1000
arg10=1000
while IFS=/ read line
do
  echo command arg1 arg2 arg3 "${line[4]}" "${line[6]}" arg6 "$arg7" arg8 arg9 "$arg10"
  arg10=$((arg10-100))
  arg7=$((arg7+100))
done < list.cqt
```

That makes the code a little bit faster and cleaner.

Comment: `$[]` is deprecated, use `$(())` (e.g. `(( arg10 -= 100 ))` or `arg10=$((arg10 - 100))`). No need for `cat`, use `done < list.cqt` (this also avoids creating a subshell so variable values are available after the loop exits. Use `while IFS=/ read -r line` instead of `tr`.

Comment: Dennis, thank you for real good tips. The only thing, I didn't catch the idea, how could IFS help us?

Comment: Here's evidence that `$[]` syntax was [deprecated long ago](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/gnu.bash.bug/HoPd5I2Zqzk). Regarding IFS, please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11476917/418413).

Comment: @kojiro: thank you very much; you mean I could use array instead of `set` + positional arguments. That is a very good idea. Thank you once again.

Comment: I know it's not hip to say I like reputation points, but *I like reputation points*. </hint>

Answer (score 3):

You can control the delimiter of the shell's `read` command via the Internal Field Separator `IFS`. If you read into an array it's easy to access the indexed values. Then it becomes a simple matter of looping over the input and updating your counter variables. If you save the arguments to an array, you can just pass the expanded array as the arguments to your command.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Use set -x to see if the array "args" is getting assigned the values you expect.
IFS='/'
counter=-1000
while read -a fields; do
    (( counter+=100 ))
    args=(
        'arg1' 'arg2' 'arg3'
        "${fields[4]}" "${fields[6]}" 'arg6'
        $counter 'arg8' 'arg9' $(( -1 * counter ))
    )
    # command "${args[@]}"
done < list.cqt
```

Comment: I don't really think it's necessary to create an array (`args`), just put the arguments after `command`. It's not really a good idea to increment the counter as a side effect. An explicit, separate increment statement is better practice for readability and maintainability.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson you have a point about the counter (edited); however, putting the arguments into an array allows you to write it on multiple lines without backslash-escaping newlines, which is a risky practice.